# How can I get the perpendicular distances between each boundary point to the hough line?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

This is my input picture.

[image]

The yellow points on the curve are given by the "drawcountours" method and the blue straight line is obtained by the hough line.
here is the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# from scipy.cluster.vq import vq, kmeans
import numpy as np
import glob



images = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Desktop\dist.png')

for fname in images:

  Image = cv2.imread(fname)

  gray = cv2.cvtColor(Image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  ret,seg = cv2.threshold(gray,40,250,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

  # cv2.imshow('H',seg)
  # cv2.waitKey(0)


  total=0
  _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(seg, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
  for c in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) >80 and cv2.contourArea(c) <2000:
      M = cv2.moments(c)
      cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
      cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

      epsilon = 0.001 * cv2.arcLength(c, True)
      approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, epsilon, True)
      total+=1

      cv2.drawContours(Image, approx, -1, (0, 255, 255), 5)

  cv2.imshow('l',Image)
  cv2.waitKey(0)

  lines = cv2.HoughLines(seg, 7, np.pi / 270, 300)

  for rho, theta in lines[0]:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a * rho
    y0 = b * rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000* (-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000* (a))
    x2 = int(x0 -1000 * (-b))
    y2 = int(y0 -1000 * (a))

    cv2.line(Image, (x1, y1), (x2,y2), (255, 255, 0), 2)
  cv2.imshow('l', Image)
  cv2.waitKey(0)

 ######get line equation#####
  points = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2)]
  x_coords, y_coords = zip(*points)
  A = vstack([x_coords, ones(len(x_coords))]).T
  m, c = lstsq(A, y_coords)[0]
  print("Line Solution is y = {m}x + {c}".format(m=m, c=c))
 
  #####to convert the obtained line equation to Ax+By+C=0 form###### 
  A = m
  B = -1
  C = 0
  for i in range(1, approx.shape[0]):
      
      
      per_dis = ((A * approx[i][0][0]) + (B * approx[i][0][1]) + C) / math.sqrt((A ** 2) + (B ** 2)) # the perpendicular distance
      inter_x = int(((B * (approx[i][0][0] - (A * approx[i][0][1]))) - (A * C)) / ((A ** 2) + (B ** 2)))#the x coordinate of the intersection point
      inter_y = int((A * ((-B * approx[i][0][0]) + (A * approx[i][0][1])) - (B * C)) / ((A ** 2) + (B ** 2)))#the y coordinate of the intersection point
     
      cv2.line(Image, (approx[i][0][0],approx[i][0][1]), (inter_x,inter_y), (255, 0, 255), 2)# to draw the green line 

  cv2.imshow('l', Image)
  cv2.waitKey(0)
```

How can I obtain the perpendicular distances from those `contour` points( yellow points) to the `hough` line? In other words, I want the following output.

[image]

I want to display the green lines and also want to know the length of each green line.

I tried calculating the the perpendicular distance using the formulae from  Wikipedia but got the following output:

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line ?

Comment: You can check out my [houghtool](https://github.com/alkasm/houghtool/blob/master/houghtool/houghtool.py) project on GitHub---there's a lot of functions for dealing with lines in the Hough formats OpenCV uses. If you skim through that Python file, you'll see some distance functions including `point_line_dist(point, line)`. You can clone the repo or just steal that function, it will work with your line. Otherwise, the link Dan posted specifically shows the determinant formula I used for lines defined by two points, which you have with your endpoint lines.

Comment: I need the intersection coordinates to draw the lines

Comment: I mean the coordinates of the point where the green line meets the blue line

Comment: rotate image to make Hough line horizontal, then yellow points x's are their projection on the Hough line, record the Hough line points, rotate back

Answer (score 3):

In order to get that result, you will first need to understand a few concepts.
The first concept is the line vector representation. You need to first find the vector representation of your line.

First you need to get 2 random points, a1 and a2, on your Hough Line to create a vector representation, ***A***,

***A*** = *a2* - *a1*

and vector ***B*** from

***B*** = *b1* - *a1*

With these vector you can calculate the magnitude and angle,θ using the following formula:

Magnitude = (***A<sup>T</sup> ⋅ B***) / |***A***|

θ = cos<sup>-1</sup>((***A<sup>T</sup> ⋅ B***)/ |***A***||***B***|)

Then, using the trigonometry function, you should be able to find the distance L, which is the distance between the point to the Hough Line.

[image]